# Removing Subsets and Duplicates from a list?

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects. Each object has a property called Conflicts which is a HashSet of int.

I want to remove any sets that are proper subsets, and also remove any that are duplicates  where a duplicate is if the hashsets contain the same integers:

```
private static List<ConflictGroup> RemoveSubsets(List<ConflictGroup> groups)
{
    List<ConflictGroup> results = new List<ConflictGroup>();
    foreach (var group in groups)
    {
        results.RemoveAll(r => r.Conflicts.SetEquals(group.Conflicts));
        results.RemoveAll(r => r.Conflicts.IsProperSubsetOf(group.Conflicts));
        results.Add(group);
    }
    return results;
}
```

This almost works.

If I have:

```
1
1,2
1,2,3
```

It only keeps 1,2,3.

But If I have:

```
1,
1,2,3
1,2
```

It fails and does not just return 1,2,3...

I'm not sure what I should change for it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add test if newly adding group is subset of some existing before add:

```
if(results.Any(r => group.Conflicts.IsProperSubsetOf(r.Conflicts))){ continue; }
```

You can test it even before those RemoveAll, as if it is subset of some existing group there would be no subset of this subset in the result anyway (the same stands for equality).

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's returning the last 2 lines?

The code goes through, removes all EXISTING subsets, and then adds the current one.  It should only add the current one if THAT ONE is not a subset of any that are already in there.

What happens:

- Process {1} - None removed, add {1}
- Process {1,2,3} - Remove 1 (proper subset of {1,2,3}), add {1,2,3}
- Process {1,2} - None removed ({1,2,3} is not a subset of {1,2}), add {1,2}